# Calculating c(x,t) max in a diffusion equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Solution]

In the picture one can see that the c(x1,t) max is the partial derivative of c with respect to t equal to zero.

The result is the equation on the bottom, I THINK. How does this equation represent the maximum value of c? Do I need to plug in the 0 into one of the variables? Or is this the final result, just the equation?

Secondly, in the result: Does the c(x,t) represent all the constant values of the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, physically $c(x, t)$ gives the concentration of pollutant at position $x$ and time $t$ assuming that initially all pollutant is concentrated at $x=0$. This takes the form of a spreading gaussian whose 'width' increases linearly with $t$.  Thus, initially $c(x_1, 0)=0$ but this will increase shortly afterwards as the pollutant spreads.  Then, as the pollutant spreads further, the concentration will decrease due to the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ in $c(x, t)$.  So, if we sit at $x_1$ and measure the concentration, we expect there to be a peak.

If we fix $x_1$, $c(x_1, t)$ tells us how the concentration at $x_1$ varies over time.  The condition for an extremum is $\left.\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}\right|_{x_1, t^*} = 0$ and we know physically that this extremum will be a maximum, so we we want to find the time $t^*$ when this condition is true. I've written the 'evaluated at' symbol to be explicit that $\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}$ is a function of $x, t$ and we are looking for the time $t^*$ at which this holds.

So, given the functional form you have above,
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = \Big(-\frac{1}{2t} + \frac{x^2}{4Dt^2} \Big) c(x, t)$$
you need to plug in $x_1$ and then find the time when the resulting function is 0.  As $c(x, t)$ is positive for $t>0$, you can cancel it out and you only need to consider the zeros of the prefactor. So this reduces to solving
$$0 =  -\frac{1}{2t^*} + \frac{x_1^2}{4D(t^*)^2} $$
where the $t^*$ indicates that this only holds for the time $t^*$ when the concentration reaches it's peak.

Lastly, you wanted to know why $c(x,t)$ appears in the time derivative. This is just due to the properties of exponentials. Taking the derivative of an exponential will give another exponential times some terms from the chain rule. As a result, the time derivative above ends up being proportional to the original function $c(x, t)$.  Try using the product rule on a function of the form $c(t) = f(t)e^{g(t)}$, then move some things around to write the derivative as $$c'(t) = \Big( \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} + g'(t)\Big)c(t).$$
Physically, the $c(x, t)$ in the time derivative above is telling you that the rate at which the concentration is changing is proportional to the amount of pollutant at that location.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I understand the logic until this: As c(x,t)c(x,t) is positive for t>0t>0, you can cancel it out and you only need to consider the zeros of the prefactor.
 What does that mean,that with time > 0 you can cancel out c(x.t)? Thank you!

Comment: @VeraMarya I've added some clarification to that section.  Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes this is very helpful!. Tomorrow is the exam and this might be the most important to understand so detailledly! :)